# How to verify listening port number on SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like to find out the listening port number that is on the SQL server. This have to be done via transact sql. Also, is there any way to know whether is this a static or dynamic port?

I have tried google thus far but have no success thus far.

Running T-SQL scripts returned the following error:

```
RegOpenKeyEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Comment: You should google about the error.

Comment: If you can't get the posted answer working you could try `EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0,1,'listening'`

Comment: [See also this similar question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6872/3690)

Answer (score 2):

http://smartypeeps.blogspot.com/2006/11/t-sql-script-to-find-nw-port-of-sql.html

```
set nocount on
DECLARE @test varchar(20), @key varchar(100)
if charindex('\',@@servername,0) <>0
begin
set @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server\'
+@@servicename+'\MSSQLServer\Supersocketnetlib\TCP'
end
else
begin
set @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer \Supersocketnetlib\TCP'
end

EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
@key=@key,@value_name='Tcpport',@value=@test OUTPUT

SELECT 'Server Name: '+@@servername + ' Port Number:'+convert(varchar(10),@test)
```

**OR**

http://sql-articles.com/blogs/how-to-find-tcpip-port-via-t-sql/

```
DECLARE @key VARCHAR(50), @RegistryPath VARCHAR(200)

IF (SERVERPROPERTY('INSTANCENAME')) IS NULL    
BEGIN    
SET @RegistryPath='Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\'    
END    
ELSE    
BEGIN    
SET @RegistryPath='Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),SERVERPROPERTY('INSTANCENAME')) + '\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\'    
END    
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @RegistryPath, 'tcpPort'
```

Both executed and returns the current TCP/IP Port number.

Comment: And another one: http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/06/tcp-port-of-sql-server.html

Comment: is there actually a way to verify whether this port is static or dynamic?

Comment: Static for sure. SQL Server does not choose random port.

Comment: under the SQL Configuration Manager it allows dynamic port setting

Comment: under client protocols, TCP IP, there is no dynamic port setting. Where are you looking at?

Comment: i get a null value returned for the 3rd link u gave. the other 2 link u gave came up as error !:(

Comment: I executed the two sql scripts. Working find. As you can see the script are accessing the registry, maybe the account from which you are running does not have access. You can update the OP with the error.